# react native Flatlist re rendering elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In the following code, there is an array of 200 elements. And I am using Flatlist to render elements of the array. But renderItems function is called for first 10 elements and then for first 20 elements including first 10 elements and then for first 30 elements including first 20 elements and so on. I expect renderItems function to be called once for each item and only for the items which are displayed on the screen. What should I change in my code?

````
import {View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';
const numbers = Array.from(Array(200), (_, i) => i);

const renderItems = (item) => {
  console.log('Render Items == ', item.item);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 40,
          fontWeight: '400',
          textAlign: 'center',
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        {item.item}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
      }}>
      <FlatList
        data={numbers}
        renderItem={renderItems}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.toString()}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;```
````

Comment: In your expected scenario, let's say, you would like to change the style of existing elements (reduce the height as an example, to provide a more compact layout) as the user scrolls down. It would be very difficult IMO. The `renderItem` also receives an index value. You may use it to check if you are in the first 10 or second 10 etc.

Comment: use `onEndReached ` for pagination.